# Clinical Notes (SOAP) representation FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

My question is more about modeling simple clinical notes in SOAP (Subjective, Objective, Assessment, Plan) into the FHIR specification.

I have been trying to look into the documentation but it doesn't provide a clear way of doing it or a clear way of which resources to use.

Does anyone have an idea of the best resources to use from FHIR for clinical notes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most EHRs will utilize [DocumentReference](https://hl7.org/fhir/documentreference.html) and [Binary](https://hl7.org/fhir/binary.html). DocumentReference would hold the metadata about the note, such as the author and creation date/time. Binary would hold the content in a base64-encoded string.

There is the possibility of forgoing the Binary and using the `content.attachment.data` attribute in DocumentReference to directly hold the base64-encoded string, but this isn't as common.